# Sticky navbar not working with parallax

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a site where all pages have a header and a navbar just below it.
when the page is scrolled and the navbar reaches the top of the screen, javascript allows it to stick and remain at the top of the screen.

On one of my pages I am using a pure parallax scrolling effect using HTML5 and CSS3. The problem is, it seems that the javascript can't detect when the navbar reaches the top of the screen, with this effect active.

Can anyone give me advice on how to proceed and get javascript to detect the position, or what can i do to get my parallax effect to run from just below the navbar so that the navbar is totally separate from the effect.`

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
  window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

  // Get the navbar
  var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

  // Get the offset position of the navbar
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

  // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
  function myFunction() {
     if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
       navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } 
   else {
       navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
     }
  } 
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);

html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {  
 
 background: #222222;
 margin:0;
 padding:0px;
 perspective: 1px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 height: 100%;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   font-family: Nunito;
}
h2 {
   font-size: 250%
}

p {
  font-size: 140%;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333;
}

.slide {
   position: relative;
   padding: 25vh 10%;
   min-height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
 transform-style: inherit;
}
#img2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-104%) translateY(-100%) rotate(9deg);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
#img2:last-of-type{transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-194%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
#img1:last-of-type {
  transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-104%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);
}

.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 100;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
  margin-left: 100;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slide, .slide:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;  
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}

#title {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/");
  z-index:2;
}

#title h1 {
 transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75);
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;

}

#slide1:before {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

#slide2 {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/3/");
  z-index:2;
}

#slide3:before {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/5/");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

#slide4 {
  background: #222;
 hight:100%;
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);
body {
    min-height:100%; 
    position:relative; 
    padding-bottom:20px; 
}
/*header position and styling*/
header {
 Position: absolute;
 background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
 height: 120px;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 padding: 5px;
 border: #000000;
 z-index: 50;
}
.headerlogo {
 opacity: 0.8;
 Position: absolute;
 top: 5;
 width: 21%;
 height: 110px; 
 z-index: 51;
}
.headerContent {
    position: absolute;
 right: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: #25FF25;
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 51;
}
 /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
nav {
 Position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 128px;
 z-index: 55;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
nav a {
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
 float: left;
}
/* Change the color of links on hover */
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
 float: left;
}
/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
 left: 8px;
}
/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
 float: left;
}
/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
 float: left;
}
/* Fixed/sticky icon bar (vertically aligned 35% from the top of the screen) */
.icon-bar {
 left: 0;
   position: fixed;
 z-index: 50;
   top: 35%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* Style the icon bar links */
.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/* Style the social media icons with color, if you want */
.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

/* Copyright footer-wrap */
footer {
   position: absolute; 
    left: 0 ; right: 0; bottom: 0; 
    height:20px;
}
footer a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}
footer a:hover {
   color: #000;  
}
footer p {
 color: #BBBBBB;
   padding: 0px 0;
 text-align: center;
}
footer h2 {
   color: #fff;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0 0px; 
 text-align: center;
}
/* Add padding to container elements */
.containers {
 font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 17px;
   color: #000;
 text-shadow: none;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
   padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
   border: 1px solid lightgrey;
   border-radius: 3px;
 width: 500px; 
}
* {box-sizing: border-box}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
 display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1000; /* Sit on top */
    left: 30%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 40%; /* Full width */
    height: 80%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: #474e5d;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
 background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 10% auto 5% 16%; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 66%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Elusen Rave</title>
 <!--Page Stylesheet-->
 <link href="Stylesheets/moreinfo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!--Site Stylesheet-->
 <link href="Stylesheets/Universal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!-- Load font awesome icons -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <style>
  footer {
     position: absolute; 
   z-index: 50;
      left: 0 ; right: 0; bottom: 150px;    
  }
  span {
   
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
   font-size: 40%;
   text-decoration: none;
     font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <header>
  <div class="headerContent">
   <p>
   <h3>Brought to you by: </h3>
   <h1>Polokwane Events</h1>
     </p>
  </div>
  <img class="headerlogo" src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/" alt="Header logo">
 </header>
 <nav id="navbar">
  <!-- Top nav bar -->
   <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="moreinfo.html" class="active">More info</a>
  <a href="RaveMedia.html">Media</a>
  <a href="Donatios.html">Donation</a>
  <a href="bookings.html">Bookings</a>
  <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">Credits</a>  
 </nav> 
 <!-- The social media icon bar -->
 <div class="icon-bar">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/?request_context=signup" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/people" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/feed/" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
 </div>
 
 <!--modal and form-->
  <div id="id01" class="modal">
     <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
     <form class="modal-content" action="/action_page.php">
       <div class="containers">
     <h1>Home Page</h1>
     <br/>
     <p>The Home Page consist of the following: </p>
     <p>Header - Containing the logo and company name. </p>
     <p>Navigation bar - providing direct links to other pages and it sticks to the top of screen when scrolling down, it also contains the audio controls</p>
     <p>Social media sidebar - linking to different social media links and it is fixed in position </p>
     <p>Main content - Video background that gets covered with logo that is created by different parts using animations. </p>
     <p>Some text that leads to the date is also fading onto screen to try and capture attention of viewer. </p>
     <p>Footer - Copyright with links. I used an alert box to show where it would link if I had to link them. </p>
       </div>
     </form>
  </div>
 <script src="Script/Index.js"></script>
 <!--Parallax-->
 <div id="title" class="slide header">
     <h2>More Information</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="slide1" class="slide">
   <div class="title">
    <h2>The Event</h2>
    <p>This rave event is for all ages over the age of 18 all over the world. This event is brought to you by Polokwane Events. For the purpose  to raise funds for the educate homeless and disabled kids in Limpopo.</p>
   </div> 
   <img id="img2" src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
   <img id="img2" src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
  </div>

  <div id="slide2" class="slide">
   <div class="title">
    <h2>Venue</h2>
    <p>The rave will be held from 30 March 2018 till 01 may 2018 at Peter Mokaba Stadium. There is a VIP area with Smoking area, Bar, Food and Bathrooms. A Merch store, Food, Bar, Bathrooms, ATM and First Aid area will also be availible in public areas. </p>
   </div>
   <img id="img1" src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
   <img id="img1" src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
  </div>

  <div id="slide3" class="slide">
    <div class="title">
   <h2>Entertainment</h2>
   <p>Famous DJ's local and from all over the world will be performing at the venue over the coarse of three days. DJ's such as Alen Walker, David Guetta, Martin Garrix, Afrojack, Tiësto, Skrillex, Avicii, Hardwell, Paul van Dyk, Zed, Axwell and much much more....</p>
    </div>
   <img id="img2" src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
   <img id="img2" src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
  </div>

  <div id="slide4" class="slide header">
   <h2>Come and be part of the greatest Event 
   EVER!!!!!</h2>
   <footer>
   <!--Copyright and links-->
    <p><span style="color: #BBBBBB">
     &copy; 2018 Danie Nortje
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     Design by </span><span style="color: #fff" <a href="#openModal">Danie Nortje</a> 
       <a href="http://www.cssportal.com/">CSS Portal </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <a href="index.html">Home</a> |
       <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Sitemap</a> |
       <a href="#" onClick="alert('This should link to RSS Feed when clicked')">RSS Feed</a> |
       <a href="#" onClick="alert('This should link to HTML5 TERMS OF USE when clicked')">HTML5</a> |
       <a href="#" onClick="alert('This should link to CSS3 TERMS OF USE when clicked')">CSS3</a>
     </span>
    </p>
   </footer>
  </div>
 
 
</body>

</html>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I eventually found out how to get parallax and sticky navbars on the same page

```
#navbar{
position: fixed;
right: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change the nav position to sticky.

```
nav {
Position: sticky;
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 128px;
z-index: 55;
background-color: #333;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried that, but then the navbar sticks to the initial position and don't scroll to the top of the screen where the sticky effect must take effect.

Comment: The navbar is supposed to scroll up about 120px then stick to the position, when you scroll back down it must release again. I have tried a few ways, but when the navbar behaves the parallax effect is gone and so on.

Comment: I found something that may be able to help you. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: that works fine on my other pages, but for some reason not with parallax. I think it has something to do with perspective: 1px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;